# problem to edit gender with radio on react

Tags: html, reactjs, node.js

I can´t change between my two radios to change the stato of gender in my form

Masculino
               setGender("masculino")}
              />
            
            
              Femenino
               setGender("femenino")}
              />

in my controller to edit:
patient.gender = gender || patient.gender;

gender is destructured from req.body.gender

I wanna edit the gender using the radio buttons

Comment: Please provide the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.